# Is it possible to use a custom html helper editor template without tying it to the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

So normally I am doing something like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDateTime)
```

Then I have a custom template DateTime.cshtml that is used as the editor.

Whatever the date value of Model.MyDateTime is will be displayed as expected, and as expected the name of the field on the next POST will be MyDateTime.

My desire is to use the custom template in the Html.EditorFor WITHOUT binding in the model object, instead I wish to give it a form field name to be POSTed but have it start out blank.

However I can't find an override of Html.EditorFor() that will allow me to not specify a model object, so I can only specify the template to use and the html form field name so it starts empty.

Note: I tried `@Html.EditorForModel("DateTime", "MyDateTime")` but just got an error so I think that I misunderstood what that is for.

(I know I could just have MyDateTime be null coming back from the controller but that is not what I am asking here.)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to use an `EditFor` that is going to edit nothing (no model passed)?  Instead of going down that road, you should probably look at using a `View` or `PartialView` which do not require having a Strongly-Typed model.

Comment: Because I have this complex custom html template that I want to use, is there not a way to use it without having to copy the code into a partial?

Comment: A template for an `EditFor` or a `PartialView` are pretty much the same idea, except one requires a strongly typed model.  Therefore, this wouldn't break anything other than the possible StackOverflow if you have partials calling themselves.

Comment: Ah so do you mean that I could just say RenderPartial and then use the custom template as my partial, or? I am just trying to avoid duping code.